# Running Azure AD powershell module from app service

Tags: powershell, azure, entra-id, azure-app-services

I'm running an App Service from which I would like to run commands from the Azure Active Directory V2 PowerShell module. I haven't found any module to do so and running a module's command result in this, logical, error :

(the example is from the MSOnline V1 PowerShell module for Azure Active Directory)

> The specified module 'MSOnline' was not loaded because no valid module
>   file was found in any module directory.

Thank you.

Comment: Any reason your trying to use app service and not azure automation?

Comment: Hello Sam. Yes in fact this woul be part of a .NET application in order to manage users' accounts. For now we are running such PW commands from an Azure VM.

Comment: If your doing this from a .net API then why not just hit the graph API using .net rather than trying to use PS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We've figured out that as @Sam Cogan said, we should switch to the grap api.